# is python glob.glob '\' robust across different OS win/unix/mac?

Tags: python, glob

I have the following code:

```
import glob
files = ".\database\*.txt"
for pathname in glob.glob(files):
    print pathname
```

I understand in different OS directory are represented differently. So I am wondering is ".\database*.txt" robust across different OS?

I tried

```
files = "./database/*.txt"
```

and it also worked.

If I want to make my code robust, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Related: [What is the preferred way to write a file path in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23529312/1258041)

Comment: your first example would likely not work (since you need to escape the `\` or use `r`aw strings .... )  I prefer the second way since it definately works across all os' (at least assuming your doing it in python)

Comment: @JoranBeasley I agree with you, but it also surprise me that the first one works on my Windows system, r'aw is definitely better though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask Python what to use:

```
In [1]: import os.path

In [2]: os.path.sep
Out[2]: '/'
```